# Time Line graph is not showing date exactly

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on time line graph i am getting From date and To date from date base. I am binding that values to time line graph through javascript. But Graph is displaying one month ahead.

Ex: My date is 12-jun-2011, but in graph I am getting near 12-july-2011.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: How are you passing the date to the graph? If you are passing month as numbers, they might be zero indexed.

Comment: Add -1 to your months - or if you show us some code we can give you more information's about your error. You have a date time conversion issue here.

Comment: What time line graph? Is it native to Asp.net? Some code and more details would help helping you.

Comment: chart to visualize events in time. The events can take place on a single date, or have a start and end date (a range). scripts.Append(makedateString(DateTime.Parse(datarow["htl_StartDate"].ToString()))); I am passing month as dd/mm/yyyy